GTM Server Side tagging for mobile apps (iOS)
We are trying to implement GTM server-side tagging for the iOS app. I have done all the required settings as provided by the official documentation link https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/server-side-tagging-for-mobile-apps. We are using manual provisioning tagging server for this. When we hit the event from the iOS app, the tag manager is not displaying any request on Quick_Preview. But the same is working for the web app. Please help me if we are missing something.
I have done all the required setups like added GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SGTM_UPLOAD_ENABLED = true, CFBundleTypeRole = None, CFBundleURLName = BUNDLE_ID, CFBundleURLSchemes = [tagmanager.sgtm.c.BUNDLE_ID] in Info.plist and added Analytics.handleOpen(:) in application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method. Also created GA4 Client for app, tags and triggers. After that followed https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/server-side-tagging-for-mobile-apps#preview-your-container these steps and open the app, getting the url: tagmanager.sgtm.c.BUNDLE_ID://preview?sgtm_preview_key=MY_PREVIEW_KEY&sgtm_debug_enable=1 in application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method. But not reflects any request on preview mode.

Please provide more details - the settings and the code you have tried. Currently, the question is very broad.

Please no not answer in comments, use the [Edit] button right under your question (before the comments section) to update the question itself.

@SENya Can you please help me for this?
